# E-Visa needed for Turkey if have a valid Residence Permit from Germany?

Tags: turkey, tourist-visas, e-visas, german-residents

I will be traveling back from India to Germany in November. I am taking **Turkish Airlines** and will have a layover in Istanbul for 30 Hours.

I am an Indian Passport holder but have a valid Residence Permit *Aufenthalstitel* in Germany. The flight details say that I can either get free accommodation or a free city tour in Istanbul but I am curious that should I apply for the **e-Visa for Single Entry** as an Indian Passport holder but have a  resident permit in Germany?

Comments and solutions appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa, your German residence permit allows you to use a single-entry e-Visa:

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks. But does that mean I still have to apply at the website? Right?

Comment: @Shan-Desai yes.  How else can you get an e-Visa other than by applying at the website?

Comment: Oh I was in a confusion that I could get the visa without applying for the visa or paying for it. So it is inevitable that I still pay for the eVisa

Comment: @Shan-Desai Either on the Website, or at the Turkish airport through kiosks. But yes, you still Need to pay for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for a Evisa a very simple process which I have done once this year. Approval speed is sameday for most cases.

Answer (score -3):

Your German resident permit does not count in this case. It would be different if you were German citizen. In this case, you need to apply for a visa for sure.

Comment: This directly contradicts the previous answer by phoog, which is backed up by a quote from the official Turkish government website.  But you've offered no supporting evidence. Can you explain what evidence leads you to think that your answer is right and the previous answer is wrong?

Comment: I meant having residence permit from Germany does not make any difference. His passport is from India, and need to apply for a visa to be able to enter Turkey.

Comment: But the quote in phoog's answer explicitly says that the residence permit **does** make a difference, and allows the traveler to get an e-Visa instead of a regular visa.

Comment: I checked Turkish translation as well. It is said that if you fulfill certain conditions (which are not written, better to be asked), you can get e-visa. But not sure what those conditions are. To make sure, I would ask the embassy or apply directly to the embassy.

Comment: As a German citizen, you would need no e-visa (this is quite an exception, for example UK citizen need an e-visa, and this has nothing to do with EU membership). As an Indian citizen, Turkey's rules for Indian citizens apply, and Turkey's rules say that Indian citizens with a German residence permit can get an e-visa.